# How to find correct details for PHPMyAdmin database?

Tags: php, android, phpmyadmin, hosting

I have created a `MySQL` database within `phpmyadmin` on http://www.hosting24.com/ but I am unsure where to find my details in order to correctly link my `Android Application` to it using `PHP scripts`.

I.e I do not know these details, and want to know where I could find them?

```
$mysql_host = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$mysql_user = "";
$mysql_password = "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking on your database in phpMyAdmin, you may (or may not) see a "Privileges" tab where you can add users.

[image: phpmyadmin]

If not, go to the "MySQL Databases" page in hosting24's cPanel site and you'll see the relevant option at the bottom.

Comment: thanks, I can see the MYSQL databases tab but theres is currently no users registered, there is an option to add a new user and password? But i still do not know my host and database?

Comment: Do I basically create a new user in here and then add them to the database?

Comment: That's right. For the host field, that is the host you will be connecting FROM. If you will be connecting from anywhere, you'll have to select "any host". In your application, the host you need to use should be shown at the top of phpMyAdmin, or on the phpMyAdmin homepage. If it says "localhost" then you'd better ask hosting24

Comment: Yes it says local host? Is that an issue? Thank you for your help

Comment: It just means it's not clear what you should be connecting to, so just ask hosting24 for the address.

Comment: I really should reiterate the points of others though, unless you're making a read-only user, this will be very insecure if you are going to connect directly from your Android app. Obviously, connecting from PHP should be safe enough.

Comment: Yes thanks I am connecting via a php script, will the scripts not work if I enter local host as address?

Comment: That depends if the MySQL server is on the same server as your PHP. Give it a try, if it doesn't work then ask hosting24 for the correct address

Answer (score 0):

These details would come from your hosting provider, likely in the control panel that gave you the link to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Furthermore, your android application cannot be connected via localhost, so you will need to create a wildcard SQL user in your hosting control panel.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Ultimately, an Android application shouldn't be connecting to MySQL directly **at all**. An API should be constructed.

Comment: Yes so how do I create a wildcard user? Thanks

Comment: @ryni201400 You should **not do so**. You should be building an API so you don't put your database's credentials in your Android app's code, where it can be found and abused.

Answer (score 0):

go to phpmyadmin, find your database then go to the privileges, and you will find all the database info, click edit privileges to modify existing values.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzBDF.png]